# converting a ascii to int

Tags: c

gcc 4.5.1 c89

I have a buffer that is filled with char characters. I need to compare them:

This is a sample contents of the buffer:

```
vote buffer [ 51 ]
vote buffer [ 32 ]
vote buffer [ 49 ]
vote buffer [ 32 ]
vote buffer [ 50 ]
vote buffer [ 32 ]
vote buffer [ 53 ]
vote buffer [ 32 ]
```

I am trying to get the int equivalent of these char's that are in the buffer to compare.

```
#define NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES 7
if((vote_data.vote_buff[i] > NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES || vote_data.vote_buff[i] < 1) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

As you can see it will never be true in the if statement as the range is far greater.

I have tried casting to (int). However, that didn't solve the problem.

I guess I could calculate from the ascii character set. However, I would rather not add more complexity if I cannot help it.

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: I don't understand your problem. For sure, vote buffer[0] which is 51, is greater than NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES which is 7. Could you be a bit more precise?

Comment: 51 is the ascii character 3. So I need to compare 3 with the NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATES. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to convert single characters to `int`, you can use `c - '0'` (which is equivalent to `c - 48`).  If you want to convert strings of more than a single character, use [`sscanf()`](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/sscanf.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can use atoi to convert strings as integers. Char and int are the same in C

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 int n=65;


 char* String;

 String="1234";


 printf("String: %s - Integer: %d\n", String, atoi(String));


 printf("int %d is char: %c\n ", n, n);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in to the standard library to turn a `char` into an `int`.  This is because most `int`s don't fit in a `char`.  There are however, several ways to turn a string into an `int`, because that is much more commonly done.  You can easily use these by copying each `char` into a the first element of length 2 array with the second char 0, and using this as input to either `atoi()`, `sscanf()`, or `strtol()`.  (I'd recommend one of the last two in a real program, as they allow error checking.)

```
char buffer[2] = {0,0};
int i;

for (i = 0; i < vote_count; ++i) {
    int vote;
    buffer[0] = vote_data.vote_buff[i];
    vote = atoi(buffer);
    /* handle vote */
}
```

Using the ASCII values and subtracting `'0'` is certainly a workable option.  Any reasonable character set will have the digits in order.

Best yet would be to change the interface so that your routine doesn't receive an array of `char`, but an array of `int`.  The external interfaces of the program should be responsible for sanitizing input and turning it into something easy to process.  Currently, there is no way to easily change the program to support more than ten candidates.  Letting the input routines store `int`s fixes this.