# i keep getting segmentation fault when running this code

Tags: c, recursion

this code is to convert a string input to int without using atoi fiunction and i'm making it for CS50 Pset3

- variable number of type int is to store  string input in because there is no way to to use variable of type string in the calculations of the code
- the strcmp in conditoin of the array is the base case used to keep the programm from running endlessly
- gets the last left number

```
int temporary = number % 10;
```

- shortens the number by moving the null pointer one position to the left

  ```
  number = number - temporary / 10;
  ```

  and I have 2 problems

1- i keep getting segmentation fault when running this code

2- i need to konw how to call the recursive function

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int convert(string input);

int main(void)
{
    string input = get_string("Enter a positive integer: ");

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            printf("Invalid Input!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Convert string to int
    printf("%i\n", convert(input));
}

int convert(string input)
{

// stores the input in a variable called number  
    int number = (long) input;


// the base case for the recursion to stop from running endlessly
    if (strcmp(input, "\0") == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
//   gets the last left number
        int temporary = number % 10;
//shortens the number by moving the null pointer on position to the left
        number = number - temporary / 10;
// 2nd question
        return temporary + convert(input) * 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int number = (long) input;` doesn't convert a string to a number.

Comment: The line `int number = (long) input;` doesn't do what you think it does.  It copies the address of the string to `number`, truncating it and otherwise mutilating it. The address bears no relation to the value represented by the string.  You imply that you can't use `atoi()` — what about `atol()` or `strtol()` or `strtoimax()`?  You need to emulate what those do, anyway.

Comment: i can't use any of those because this is not the purpose of the code, the purpose is to convert a numeric input of type string not literal to an integer without using atoi and any other similar function

Comment: the input is numeric not literal

Comment: Start with a simpler problem. Convert one character to a digit.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4279685/3476780) should be helpful

Comment: This is another example of needlessly using recursion for an iterative problem.  It makes no sense.  Perhaps the people who assigned this to you wanted you to use recursion, but if so, then it was a poor example.  Keep in mind that in many cases, people who teach programming classes are incompetent programmers (or not programmers at all).  The right way to use recursion is to apply it to a problem that actually *benefits* from it.

Comment: This question fits better here https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `cs50.h`, and a quick google search tells me it's a library to make certain things easier.  I assume that's why you can cast a `string` to a `(long)` like that, and why you don't need to prefix it like `std::string`.  So, I may be off-base here, but I'll tell you some things that I see here:

1. `strcmp(input, "\0") == 0` seems unlikely to work like you expect (though again, I'm not familiar with `cs50.h` and its abilities).  A `string` isn't likely to contain an actual null value, since the null value typically indicates the end of a string of characters.  Instead, check your library for the existence of something like `input.isEmpty()`, `input == ""`, or `input.length() == 0`.
2. I don't see anywhere in the code that actually shrinks the value of `input`.
3. Your question of how to make a recursive call, you're doing it!  However, `input` never changes, so you're going to wind up with an infinite loop of recursion.

I suspect based on all of these, you're actually blowing up your stack (aka a stack overflow, no pun intended) with infinite recursion.  You call `convert("10")` and that function calls `convert("10")`, and that function calls `convert("10")`, repeat, repeat, repeat..... until eventually it fails because the stack gets too full.

**EDIT**

I see now this doesn't have a c++ tag.  The casting to `(long)` REALLY won't work the way you think if `string` is actually a typedef to `char*`... I'm no C expert, but I believe it would interpret the address to a number, (specifically `long`).  My point #1 may not be valid.  T but the fact that `input` never changes and that you're making a recursive infinite loop would definitely be bad.

Comment: You're talking about c++ an not c

Comment: In this context, there's no significant difference between `"\0"` and `""` (both are empty strings, though the first has two consecutive null bytes).  The course teaches C, not C++, and there's no cast that will convert the pointer into a number based on what the pointer points to.

Comment: A cs50 `"string"` is just a typedef for `char*`.

Comment: Aha, so I was off-base.  I thought I remembered the post having a c++ tag.